# To Pull records between two dates in db2

Tags: db2

I tried below two ways they not working

```
Select * from Table 
where SERV_DATE BETWEEN '03/01/2013'AND    
              '03/31/2013'
```

ALSO This is not working

```
Select * from Table 
where SERV_DATE BETWEEN DATE('03/01/2013') AND     
              DATE('03/31/2013')
```

What should be the correct format ?

Comment: Try `between'2013-03-01' and '2013-03-31'`

Comment: i saw the table entry it has 04/01/2013  04/30/2013
why would db2 give error on the same format and will go well when given different format

Comment: I Tried these below sqls:

T.D_SERV_FROM >= '03/01/2013' 
T.D_SERV_FROM <= '03/31/2013' 

T.D_SERV_FROM >= ('03/01/2013') 
T.D_SERV_FROM <= ('03/31/2013')


T.D_SERV_FROM BETWEEN  ('03/01/2013') 
and  ('03/31/2013') 

T.D_SERV_FROM BETWEEN  date ('03/01/2013') 
and  date ('03/31/2013')  
none worked

Comment: My guess is that your client program is formatting the dates based on your computer's locale settings...

Comment: What OS is your DB2 server running on?

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried what NealB suggested? The reason for not accepting 03/01/2013 as an entry date format is, that it is region dependent in the US it is March 1, 2013 an in the UK it is January 3, 2013. So without considering the local, it is not certain, what the actual date is.

"why would db2 give error on the same format and will go well when given different format" - Don't forget, that db2 is an old lady and as all old ladies she has peculiarities. You just get used to it and there will be an happy ending.

Answer (score 2):

SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE date(modifiedBy_date) between '2017-07-28' AND '2017-08-01';

Works cool for DB2.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from Table 
where SERV_DATE BETWEEN DATE('2013-03-01') AND DATE('2013-03-31');
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select * from Table 
where (SERV_DATE BETWEEN '03/01/2013'AND    
              '03/31/2013') 


Select * from Table 
where (SERV_DATE BETWEEN '2013-03-01'AND    
              '2013-03-31')
```

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low quality. If it answers the question, consider adding a bit of text to explain how it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
select count(*) from   TABLE where time_stamp BETWEEN DATE('2018-01-01') AND DATE('2018-01-31');
```

Here time_stamp is field name and copy your timestamp filed name instead of time_stamp.